# How to get data from USDA in r

Tags: r

I need for some code examples to get data from [USDA](https://www.usda.gov/) in R.
To be more specific, I want to get [WASDE](https://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/) report data in R.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it displays no research effort, just asks for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(readr)
wasde0919 <- read_table2("Downloads/wasde0919.txt")
View(wasde0919)
```

You will need to post-process the data!
[image]